# Autogenerated id on view emberjs

Tags: ember.js, auto-generate

Hi i´m new at Embers and at stackoverflow. I´ve been working on this issue for a week. I´m trying to make an editable table with embers but the main problem is to autogenerate an id for my hidden TextFields. Inside my handlebar-template I´m generating this kind of textfields:

```
{{view Ember.TextField id="first_input_" class="hidden"}}
```

But I want to call a HandlebarsHelper who would give me a number for that row, something like this:

```
{{view Ember.TextField id="first_input_"{{{getId}}}  class="hidden"}}
```

Being my Handlebars Helper something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getId', function() {
    id = id + 1;
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(id);
});
```

I hope someone can help me with this, i thougth about not using Ember.TextField and just a normal imput but it could be easier to have it with ember for binding sake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that you wrongly place the quotes in the line:

```
{{view Ember.TextField id="first_input_"{{{getId}}}  class="hidden"}}
```

I'm not sure it's a typo when writing in StackOverflow, but if you're testing in chrome, I think that chrome will strip the data before outputting the HTML.

Also I think handlebar ( the templating behind ember ) will throw up a parsing error.

You can try here ( [tryhandlebarjs](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/) ) for basic handlebar templating playground.

Also, I think that the id = id + 1 has something wrong in the way that there's no instanciation whatsoever. There's a chance that the parser's triggering an error there. But I would have to make some checks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do:  {{view Ember.TextField id="{{{getId}}}"  class="hidden"}}, and in your helper Handlebars.registerHelper('getId', function() { return (App.genID = App.genID + 1;}); ( Remember to setup App.genID = 0; somewhere before ).